# SFTP connection in cmd prints "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2" and hangs

Tags: cmd.exe, sftp

I am not able to connect SFTP via `cmd`.
Problem is it shows *"Connected"* but after that it get hangs and finally will display error message *"Connection closed by remote host."* It's not asking for credentials.

```
ftp> open ftp.example.com 22
Connected to ftp.example.com
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
Connection close by remote host.
ftp>
```

I can login to the `ftp.example.com` host in WinSCP.

Does anyone have any idea about resolution?

Answer (score 5):

You are connecting with an FTP client (`ftp`) to an SFTP/SSH server.

FTP and SFTP are two completely different and incompatible protocols.

Use an SFTP client. WinSCP supports both SFTP and FTP. And it defaults to SFTP. So it's quite likely that you are using SFTP in WinSCP GUI.

WinSCP has [command-line interface suitable for automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) too. WinSCP GUI can even [generate a script template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) for you. If you have a working FTP script for Windows ftp, there a [guide to convert it to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).